# Skew text in Photoshop without transform

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, transform

I have a PSD file with a multiline skew text and I need to know how to do the same thing from the scratch.

I am not so good at Photoshop, and the only way I know is applying skew transform to the text object. However, internal transform matrix has no rotation elements.

So the question: is it possible to skew text without using transforms?

[image]

Comment: Why is a skew transformation undesired?? As far as I'm aware, that is the *only* option.

Comment: I am writing PSD rendering software and I need to reproduce that effect. In general, skew transform would be fine, but internally it looks different and I suppose there is another way to achieve that.

Comment: What does this have to do with design then???

Answer (score -1):

Go to Edit>Transform>Skew and move the point while holding Shift.

Comment: Hi user14975. Thank you for your answer. The question however is if it is possible _without_ using transforms, while choosing edit > transform is definitely a transform.